# Facebook Graph API explorer is not returning facebook photos How to fix this Issue?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to access user uploaded photos from facebook developers API. But the below Query created in facebook API explorer tool is not working either in API explorer tool or in node.js.

```
GET : me?fields=id,short_name,birthday,gender,photos.limit(10){album,picture,icon}
```

[image: facebook API explorer tool]

**result :**

```
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "short_name": "Raj",
  "birthday": "08/15/1997",
  "gender": "male"
} // No photos property
```

I have enabled the *user_photo* permission as well

[image]

After debugging the *access_token* result is :

[image: dubug result]

Answer (score 0):

The related App should have the `user_photos` Permission. [Regarding to the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#uploaded-photos):

> For any photos uploaded by someone, and any photos in which they have
>   been tagged - A user access token for that person with `user_photos`
>   permission.

You can double check that the token you are using for the API Request have the valid permission/scope with the [Access Token Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) tool, [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) also could be useful during the testing phase

Comment: Thanks, @Matteo for specifying Access Token Debugger. But I have already given permission to access user_photos please check above I have updated my question for better clarity.